# PostgreSQL Inserting into 2 tables?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.5

Working with a nodejs server, and I thought instead of having to do 2 method calls, with each separate function, I would call one query to add the 2 to the database. I've searched around abit on stack overflow for some questions regarding this, however they seem to not work.

My example would be that at the register phase, the user is inserted into the database, and then a sub user table called user_settings is added with a relational key to the user id of the created user.

One example that I tried but didn't work is this:

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname)
   VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
   RETURNING id AS user_id
   )
, ins2 AS (
   INSERT INTO user_settings(user_id, adddetails)
   SELECT user_id, 'foobar' FROM ins1
   )
```

It doesn't seem to know the returning user_id when I try and put it in as a query.

Answer (score 0):

Your CTE is missing a final statement. The second insert should be "outside" a CTE definition:

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname)
   VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
   RETURNING id AS user_id
)
INSERT INTO user_settings(user_id, adddetails, "timestamp")
SELECT user_id, 'foobar', current_timetamp
FROM ins1;
```

Comment: Sorry for asking again, tried to adapt my script to this principle however I seem to still have errors. I've tried this https://hastebin.com/ovaxilapiz.sql

Comment: @WilliamPfaffe: you can not combine `values()` **and** a SELECT source for an INSERT. Your sample doesn't make sense to me. Are you trying to get data from two source for the final INSERT? The `SELECT user_id from user_settings` does not seem to make any sense as you are _inserting_ into `user_settings` at that point. If you want to supply additional values, just add the columns and the values

Comment: What I would want to do, is to insert the user, then insert data into the user_settings table with the given user id from creating the user, as the user_settings has a relational key called user_id which points to the user it belongs to.

Comment: which is exactly what the statement in my answer does